# Getting colour of raster for specific value based on its symbology using ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects, symbology, .net

For the software I'm working on I'm trying to get the colour that a raster would be using to display any given value based on the symbology set up for it.

I've been more or less able to work this out for classified value type symbology as I can get the ranges and colours for each class (although in some cases the colours seem to be reversed in memory and I'm not sure I've worked out why).

For rasters that use a stretch type symbology I've had issues. I tried estimating the correct colour by taking the range of values and dividing them up by the number of colours in the colour ramp. That came close, but some raster symbologies don't use the colour ramp quite so linearly.

Then I found the IRasterRendererClassInfo interface and queried it for the class breaks. That came out even worse. For the raster I checked there were 255 classes. The first 254 of them slowly progressed along the value range of the raster (0.25589269399642944 - 123.88532257080078). But the last break went from 59.79085994126185 to 123.88532257080078. That doesn't match up with how the raster is actually coloured.

Is there a reliable way of doing this?

At the moment I'm trying to match up values with the symbology, but if it helps, I can try query via points on the map.

Here's some code showing my current attempts:

```
Public Structure colourStore
    Public borderColour As Color
    Public fillColour As Color
    Public minRange As System.Object
    Public maxRange As System.Object

End Structure
Public Function GetColoursForRasterLayer(ByVal rasterLayer As IRasterLayer)
    Dim colourList As List(Of colourStore) = New List(Of colourStore)

    If TypeOf rasterLayer.Renderer Is IRasterStretchColorRampRenderer Then
        Dim castRenderer As IRasterStretchColorRampRenderer = rasterLayer.Renderer
        Dim minValue As Double = CType(castRenderer, IRasterStretchMinMax).StretchMin
        Dim maxValue As Double = CType(castRenderer, IRasterStretchMinMax).StretchMax
        'If the layer isn't visible, the colour ramp won't be built yet
        If castRenderer.ColorRamp.Size = 0 Then
            castRenderer.ColorRamp.Size = 255
            Dim ok As Boolean = True
            castRenderer.ColorRamp.CreateRamp(ok)
        End If
        Dim rasterRendererClassInfo As IRasterRendererClassInfo = castRenderer
        Dim minVal, maxVal As Double
        Dim result As Integer

        Dim stretchSteps As Integer = rasterRendererClassInfo.ClassCount
        Dim convertedColour As IRgbColor = New RgbColor
        Dim rasterColour As IColor
        Dim stretchMin, stretchMax As Double
        rasterRendererClassInfo.QueryNumberClass(0, minVal, maxVal, result)
        stretchMin = minVal
        rasterRendererClassInfo.QueryNumberClass(stretchSteps - 1, minVal, maxVal, result)
        stretchMax = maxVal

        For counter = 0 To stretchSteps - 1
            Dim addColour As colourStore = New colourStore
            rasterRendererClassInfo.QueryNumberClass(counter, minVal, maxVal, result)
            'Convert the values from the actual values in the raster to the pixel value the symbology is using
            addColour.minRange = (minVal - stretchMin) / (stretchMax - stretchMin) * (maxValue - minValue) + minValue
            addColour.maxRange = (maxVal - stretchMin) / (stretchMax - stretchMin) * (maxValue - minValue) + minValue
            'The colours are in reverse order if the raster stretch is set to invert
            If CType(castRenderer, IRasterStretch).Invert Then
                rasterColour = castRenderer.ColorRamp.Color(stretchSteps - counter - 1)
            Else
                rasterColour = castRenderer.ColorRamp.Color(counter)
            End If

            convertedColour.RGB = rasterColour.RGB
            Dim outColour As Drawing.Color = Drawing.Color.FromArgb(convertedColour.Red, convertedColour.Green, convertedColour.Blue)

            addColour.fillColour = outColour
            addColour.borderColour = outColour
            colourList.Add(addColour)

        Next
    End If
    Return colourList
End Function
```